# How to use joins to cross check data from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I got a few tables which I need to query to crosscheck information.
All tables are in the same database.

First table is named Confirmedsitesv2 and contains a column named sites.

Sedond table is named Standardwithmail and contains three columns. sites, username and mail.

Third table named CDDump contains alot of columns but there is only three I am intrested in. Uid, employeenddate and company.

I need to query so I get site, username and mail based on the following criteria.

Site from standardwithmail matches site in confirmedsitesv2, username from standardwithmail matches uid in CDDUmp, while the employmentenddate = 0 and company is not like %test%. Mail should not be matched with anything as it only occurs in standardwithmail but will show for all the hits from the query.

So I tryed to get my head around this with left joins for nearly two hours.

Anyone experienced who can who can explain how I should use join in this situation? I done outer joins before for totaly different case and that worked easy and fine, but can't get my head around this even after alot of time on google.

If needed I can create some fake tables and upload pictures as I can't show the real data here.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (All as formatted text, not images.) Also show us your current query attempt. BTW, consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before you spend too much time.

Comment: What is it exactly that you can't do? It sounds like you need to use.  Select {stuff} from {table1}  join {table2} on table1.col = table2.col.

Comment: @Gatewarden why not? That should work.

Comment: use Volvoreports
go
select site, username, mail
from Standardwithmail
left join VCDDump on VCDDump.uid = dbo.Standardwithmail.Username where Site in (select Site from Confirmedsitesv2), employmentEnd like '0' and companyName not like '%hcl%'
order by Site;
- Mail I can get this to work and that has worked all along, it's how to get the mail that I can't even near get my head around

Comment: Hey, that last comment should have been an edit to your question instead!

Comment: You need to use inner joins only since you are after matching records.  Outer or left joins are only used if you want non-matching records as well.

Comment: @Sunil I get the same ammount of rows in my output if I use innor or left joins, so that is a bit strange then?

Comment: That is not strange. Its just that there are no non-matching rows in your sample data. So, outer joins will yield same result as inner join. You can check the answer I have posted a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
SELECT cfrsites.sites standard.username, 
       standard.mail 
FROM   Confirmedsitesv2 cfrsites, 
       Standardwithmail standard, 
       CDDump cd 
where  cfrsites.sites = standard.site 
       and standard.username = cd.Uid
```

If you can edit your post, add the Table structure and add some insert statements that will be helpful

Comment: use Volvoreports
go
select site, username, mail
from Standardwithmail
left join VCDDump on VCDDump.uid = dbo.Standardwithmail.Username where Site in (select Site from Confirmedsitesv2), employmentEnd like '0' and companyName not like '%hcl%'
order by Site;

This is what I want to do but can't get the mail to work.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0):

So why mail did not work was because it's in the the big table I only used for other information, I renamed that column in standardwithmail and I ran:

```
select site, username, mailaddress
from Standardwithmail
left join CDDump on CDDump.uid = dbo.Standardwithmail.Username where Site in (select Site from Confirmedsitesv2) and employmentEnd like '0' and companyName not like '%test%'
order by Site;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following query. You don't need outer join or left join, but just inner joins since you only want matching records.

```
SELECT     swm.username, 
                    swm.mail 
FROM       standardwithmail swm
INNER JOIN confirmedsitesv2 csv2
     ON   swm.sites = csv2.sites
  INNER JOIN cddump cdd 
      ON   swm.username = cdd.uid
  WHERE cdd.employmentenddate = 0
       AND   
       cdd.company NOT LIKE  '‰test‰'
```